# How to retreive lists from firebase database with my model class

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, model

[Here is my Firebase Database Node which i want to retreive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9wkS.png)

Hello Everyone,
I am trying to retreive arraylist from firebase and want to get them through my model class. However i stored the data through same model class but can't retreive. Here is my model class

```
public class PickupRequestsInfo implements Serializable {
    Double lat , lng;
    ArrayList<Double> listDestLat , listDestLng;
    ArrayList<String> listDestination , listReceiverName , listReceiverMob , listParcelWeight , 
    listParcelSze;

    public PickupRequestsInfo() {
    }

    public PickupRequestsInfo(Double lat, Double lng, ArrayList<Double> listDestLat, ArrayList<Double> 
    listDestLng,
                              ArrayList<String> listDestination, ArrayList<String> listReceiverName,
                              ArrayList<String> listReceiverMob, ArrayList<String> listParcelWeight,
                              ArrayList<String> listParcelSze) {
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lng = lng;
        this.listDestLat = listDestLat;
        this.listDestLng = listDestLng;
        this.listDestination = listDestination;
        this.listReceiverName = listReceiverName;
        this.listReceiverMob = listReceiverMob;
        this.listParcelWeight = listParcelWeight;
        this.listParcelSze = listParcelSze;
    }

    public Double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(Double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public Double getLng() {
        return lng;
    }

    public void setLng(Double lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }

    public ArrayList<Double> getListDestLat() {
        return listDestLat;
    }

    public void setListDestLat(ArrayList<Double> listDestLat) {
        this.listDestLat = listDestLat;
    }

    public ArrayList<Double> getListDestLng() {
        return listDestLng;
    }

    public void setListDestLng(ArrayList<Double> listDestLng) {
        this.listDestLng = listDestLng;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getListDestination() {
        return listDestination;
    }

    public void setListDestination(ArrayList<String> listDestination) {
        this.listDestination = listDestination;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getListReceiverName() {
        return listReceiverName;
    }

    public void setListReceiverName(ArrayList<String> listReceiverName) {
        this.listReceiverName = listReceiverName;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getListReceiverMob() {
        return listReceiverMob;
    }

    public void setListReceiverMob(ArrayList<String> listReceiverMob) {
        this.listReceiverMob = listReceiverMob;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getListParcelWeight() {
        return listParcelWeight;
    }

    public void setListParcelWeight(ArrayList<String> listParcelWeight) {
        this.listParcelWeight = listParcelWeight;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getListParcelSze() {
        return listParcelSze;
    }

    public void setListParcelSze(ArrayList<String> listParcelSze) {
        this.listParcelSze = listParcelSze;
    }
}
```

Here is the code which i used to retrieve

```
       pRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("PickupRequests");
        pRef.child(senderId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.hasChildren()){
                    info = dataSnapshot.getValue(PickupRequestsInfo.class);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

But it whenever i tried to get any item from my Model class e.g. info.getLat().get(0)
it gives me null and throws a NULLPointerException. Please Guide me how can i get the lists from my database. Thanks in advance

Comment: However this returned me the value  ` Double lat = datasnapshot.child("lat").getValue(Double.class);`

Comment: As I see, `info.getLat()` returns a `Double` object. There is no way you can call `.get(0)` on that. Add the entire error that you and the exact line of code that produces that error. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: thanks @AlexMamo .. I found another solution. instead of getting data directly into my model class. I first created a List of type     `ArrayList<PickupRequestsInfo> requestInfos`     and adding my model class data into this list like     `info = datasnapshot.getValue(PickupRequestInfo.class);`  and then     `requestInfos.add(info);`    now i can get every data through my model class like    `Double Lat = requestInfos.get(0).getLat()`  . Hope so it helps someone else.